# Sentence similarity

Tags: clustering, text-mining

Every week I get a group of sentences (~1000) each of them may be similar. Example:

- metallica hard wired
- metallica hardwire
- metallica hardwired
- metallica hard wire
- hardwired metallica
- hardwire metallica
- hardwire

I'm using Cosine similarity to find common documents and group them.
I have realized that similar docs:

- metallica hardwire and metallica hardwired

return ~0.5 similarity.

hardwired metallica and metallica hardwire

return ~0.433

Other docs with more words return higher values. (Im using **cosine_similarity** from **sklearn.metrics.pairwise**)

I iterate over each document and get the similarity among all docs, after that I extract the highest values. (cosine similarity > 0.55)

So far is working fine but there are cases in which I can't find similar sentences unless I reduce my coefficient, doing so it may associate other values to non-related items.

I want to know what is the best technique to group common sentences from a list of sentences. Not sure if that would be semantic similarity.

Comment: Why dont you stem the sentence before using similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosine is *only* good for long documents. `example document` and `exampl docunemt` have 0 cosine similarity. Similarly, `hard wired` and `hardwired` are completely dissimilar for cosine. Because it is based on counting the number of *identical* words.

If you want letter-based similarity, consider levenshtein. But you will likely need to go to something complex n-gram based to also detect `wordA wordB` and `wordB wordA`.

Comment: get_distance('hardwire metallica','metallica hardwire') gives me a total of 16. I can think of tokenize sentence, order it and then get the distance?, when you mention complex n-gram what exactly you are referring, can you add more details? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if anyone experimented with that. ngrams are quite expensive. Levenshtein already does not scale well to large data...